# Read local text file with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to read a local text file from my local html file, so I tried to follow the solution in this thread [Javascript - read local text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file) but the suggested solution does not work for me either:

```
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                alert(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

When I call the function `readTextFile("file:///D:/test/text.txt");` no error does show up in firebug but no alert is shown neither. I use Windows und Firefox 51.0.1 (64-Bit).
I don't want to use the function `FileReader()` in combination with a button `<input type='file' onchange='openFile(event)' ...` since the text file needs to be read automatically when loading the page. So how can I make work the solution above?

Reading the thread linked it looks like others also have problems with that solution although the thread is marked as solved.

Comment: Everything is saved on my computer. Reading the thread other people couldn't solve the problem neither although the thread is marked as solved.

Comment: Why not use FileReader and the related API? I've used it before, it works.

Comment: _“Reading the thread other people couldn't solve the problem neither although the thread is marked as solved”_ – That doesn’t change what the underlying result of the other discussion is: You can not just read local files willy-nilly, because that would be a huge security issue. You need user interaction to let them select the file first.

Answer (score 9):

Complete HTML and JavaScript file as an example for reading client side data files. Client side files can only be accessed by the FileReader, specifying a user selected file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                function loadFile(o)
                {
                    var fr = new FileReader();
                    fr.onload = function(e)
                        {
                            showDataFile(e, o);
                        };
                    fr.readAsText(o.files[0]);
                }

                function showDataFile(e, o)
                {
                    document.getElementById("data").innerText = e.target.result;
                }
            </script>

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Select file to read <input type="file" onchange="loadFile(this)">
        <pre id="data"></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Neat and sweet!

Comment: I've tried several suggested solutions for this task and failed (probably my fault). But this solution worked for me first time straight out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, it's not possible to access the local file system from JavaScript, so your code example shouldn't and couldn't work because of browser security.

However, there's the `File` and `FileReader` API which would allow you to read the contents of a file from an `<input type="file" />` and is, in reality, your only option for this sort of thing - You could use `FileReader.readAsText()` to access the files contents. This is a good resource for further information:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explanation. So i don't see why the creator of the linked thread writes "got it to work on browser [..]". In consequence using the function FileReader() and defining the variable event and using `<body onload='openFile(event)'>` won't work either?

Comment: FYI If you are targeting anything below IE11, then FileReader isn't available to you : http://caniuse.com/#search=FileReader without a SHIM

Comment: @Markus - it's an old question and it's the sort of thing that probably worked in the past but has since been deprecated due to the security issues it introduces. You don't want a website to be able to 'steal' files from your computer!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve my problem is to change the text file to a `.js` file, save it in the same folder and include it in the html file by `<script src="test.js"></script>`